# How will Hazelcast VersionedPortable work with class inheritance

Tags: java, hazelcast

So we are using VersionedPortable as protocol for Hazelcast, and we know that order of the fields are important when serializing/deserializing. What we do not understand is how to handle inheritance in serialized/deserialized classes?

```
Class A {
  int one;
  int two;

  void writePortable( PortableWriter writer ) {
     writer.writeInt( "one", one );
     writer.writeInt( "two", three );
  }
}
```

```
Class B extends A {
  int three;

  void writePortable( PortableWriter writer ) {
     super.writePortable(writer);

     writer.writeInt( "three", one );
  }
}
```

Now lets say we add a field called four into Class A - then the order is broken. Four will serialized between two and three, which is not correct. The only option I can come up with is to only implement write/read-methods in the leaf classes, but will be super difficult to maintain over time. Also, if you have many leaf classes it will most likely be wrong. Is there a better way of solving this?

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on changing the hierarchy then maybe you should plan for longer term implementation.  For example, make writePortable at Class A final method so that subclasses do not implment it.  Instead define an abstract (or empty impl) writePortableSubcl() method.  In this way, writePortable at Class A looks like:

public final void writePortable(PortableWriter writer, ..) {
    // 1) write my known attributes

```
// 2) call ...
writePortableSubclass(writer);

// 3) write my remaining added attributes

// as you add more attributes to subclasses, you'll have to
// follow this pattern to keep attributes in order.  There is no magic api to do this for you.
```

}